404 после обновления страницы
Всем привет.
Столкнулся с проблемой.
При обновлении любой страницы (кроме корневой) вылетает 404.
Используется nginx. Фронт на react
Все что нашел в сети
Прописать корректный nginx конфиг в блоке location
Но у меня вроде как все и так корректно. В чем проблема не понятно.
Содержимое конфига прилагаю
    user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  https://10.10.104.219:56/;

    ssl_certificate     /app/certificate/expertsolutions.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /app/certificate/expertsolutions.key;


    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
        }

        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
        }
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
}


Странное решение нашел.
Дописал такой код для каждого адреса и заработали обновы
location /realTimeReport {
try_files $uri /index.html;
}
    location /historicReports {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

А если у меня 1000 адресов ?
